# MySQL limits on huge number return zero rows

Tags: mysql, limits

I have table about 1,000,000 rows. this query work well:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`
WHERE `articles`.`hash` NOT
IN (
'1z8y'
)
LIMIT 2000,10
```

But this query return zero rows:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles`
WHERE `articles`.`hash` NOT
IN (
'1z8y'
)
LIMIT 800000,10
```

What's my problem? Any configure or etc?

Comment: `LIMIT` is applied after `WHERE`. Are you sure you have more than 800k records where `hash` is not equal `1z8y` ?

Comment: LIMIT 800000,10 will return 10 records after 800000 records but it looks like you didn't have 800000 records which satisfy your where clause.

Comment: how many rows of data, you are getting for the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table have `1,000,000` records but It look like Table doesn't have `800000+` records where

```
`articles`.`hash` NOT
IN (
'1z8y'
)
```

But table have `2000+` records where

```
`articles`.`hash` NOT
IN (
'1z8y'
)
```

LIMIT `800000,10` will return `10 records` after `800000`th records but it looks like you didn't have `800000 records` which satisfy your where clause condition.

You can find no. of records which satisfy your where clause using this query

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM `articles`
WHERE `articles`.`hash` NOT
IN (
'1z8y'
)
```